# How to align two SVG background images and keep them responsive

Tags: css, svg

I have two SVG images which I'd like to use as a background for a web page. One image is a picture with the line at the right edge. The second one is a line which is x-axes repeated and should be connected to the line of the first image. The main issue is that I need to make sure that they are aligned and whenever user resizes the page these two images stay aligned.

[image]

On the image above the line on the right hand side (before the dotted line) should span infinitely so it means that whenever the page is resized the proportion of two images are changed but the lines are always stay connected. For that purpose the second image is created (after doted line). Unfortunately it doesn't work as expected.

**UPDATE**

Here is the demo code.

*HTML:*

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="landing-page">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="first-image"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="line">
                    <div class="second-image"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="text">Some Text Goes Here</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

*CSS:*

```
html, body, #landing-page {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#landing-page {
    background-color: #94DCED;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.content{
    width: 88%;
    height: 100vh;
}

.first-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: left bottom;
    background-image: url("./images/first-image.svg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}

.line {
    width: 12%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}

.second-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("./images/second-image.svg");
    background-position: left bottom;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: conver;
}

#landing-page > div.text {
    font-size: 3vw;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 28%;
    right: 8vw;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}
```

*SVG (first-image.svg):*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 24.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 1366 768" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1366 768;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#F5D73F;stroke:#C6BF44;stroke-width:5;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st1{fill:#29ABE2;stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st2{fill:#29ABE2;stroke:#C6BF44;stroke-width:5;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st3{fill:#FFFFFF;stroke:#C6BF44;stroke-width:5;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
</style>
<g id="Layer_1">
</g>
<g id="Layer_2">
    <path class="st0" d="M297,409C197.83,317.83,98.67,226.67-0.5,135.5L297,409z"/>
    <path class="st1" d="M332.5,399.5"/>
    <path class="st2" d="M800,408.5H297H800z"/>
    <path class="st3" d="M1004.5,562.5c-68-51.33-136-102.67-204-154"/>
    <path class="st3" d="M1366,562c-120.5-0.19-241-0.38-361.5-0.57"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

*SVG (second-image.svg):*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 24.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 5 768" style="enable-background:new 0 0 5 768;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#FFFFFF;stroke:#C6BF44;stroke-width:5;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
</style>
<path class="st0" d="M0,562c1.67,0,3.33,0,5,0"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Could you share your codes you already have or even the SVG codes?

Comment: @ArnoTenkink - I've added some code so you can get the idea.